# Android Parcelable

Tags: java, android

I have a class that controls my http communications, as well as keeps track of the http session.  The problem i'm running into is, i would like to use this class from several activities.
The only option i have found so far is making it static in the main view, but if the app sits to long in a secondary view, the static class becomes null.
I have also tried making it parcelable, but i can't pass my CookieStore or my httpContext. This means every time I go into a view, or out of a view, i have to re-authenticate against the server, causing much unnecessary traffic.

How can i pass an object via Parcelable, or is there another type of class extension that would allow me to create a persistent class that all Activity's can view?

```
public class JSON implements Parcelable {
private String URL;
private String HOSTNAME;
private Context f_context;
private DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
private CookieStore cookieStore;
private HttpContext httpContext;
protected boolean Authenticated = false;
protected long Authenticate_timeout = 0;

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("URL",URL);
    b.putString("HOSTNAME", HOSTNAME);
    b.putBoolean("Authenticated", Authenticated);
    b.putLong("Authenticate_timeout", Authenticate_timeout);
    out.writeBundle(b);
    Object[] o = new Object[4];
    o[0] = httpClient;
    o[1] = cookieStore;
    o[2] = httpContext;
    o[3] = f_context;
    out.writeArray(o);
    }
public static final Parcelable.Creator<JSON> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<JSON>() {
    public JSON createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new JSON(in);
    }

    public JSON[] newArray(int size) {
        return new JSON[size];
    }
};

private JSON(Parcel in) {
    Object[] o = in.readArray(null);
    httpClient = (DefaultHttpClient) o[0];
    cookieStore = (CookieStore) o[1];
    httpContext = (HttpContext) o[2];
    f_context = (Context) o[3];
    Bundle b = in.readBundle();
    URL = b.getString("URL");
    HOSTNAME = b.getString("HOSTNAME");
    Authenticated = b.getBoolean("Authenticated");
    Authenticate_timeout = b.getLong("Authenticate_timeout");
}

public JSON(Context context) {
    f_context = context;
    updateSettings();
    HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams
            .setConnectionTimeout(myParams, Consts.http_timeout);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, Consts.http_timeout);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
    cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? You pass an object via `Parcelable`; if you post your code maybe we can help you more.

Comment: Sounds like you want this to be a singleton.

Comment: really what i need to do is pass this class between activities, so that i don't have to re-authenticated between screen. In C, i would just put it all in a struct and pass the pointer to the struct